# Watson Python SDK: 'DetailedResponse' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

When I use the Watson Assistant sample code for Python, it works perfectly on python 3.6.5.

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'DetailedResponse' object is not subscriptable
```

when I try to execute the code in python 3.6.6
The command it is failing on is:

```
if response['output']['text']:
print(response['output']['text'][0])
```

and if I print the type of the object response, I get:

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, found the answer, I hope it helps others:

The existing code:

```
if response['output']['text']:
    print(response['output']['text'][0])
```

Modified code:

```
if response.result['output']['text']:
    print(response.result['output']['text'][0])
```

Comment: A better solution is `' '.join(response.result['output']['text'])`

Comment: Thanks for saving us time.